# When should React call AJAX request after props change?

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I used to call AJAX after props change by `ComponentWillReceiveProps()`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.foo !== this.props.foo){
       //fetch & call this.setState() asynchronously
    }
}
```

After React 16.3 `ComponentWillReceiveProps()` is going to be deprecated in the future. Instead of `ComponentWillReceiveProps()` there is a new function `getDerivedStateFromProps`, but I can't update state async.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    // I can't get access to this.props but only state

    if(nextProps.foo !== this.props.foo){
       //fetch & call this.setState() asynchronously
    }

    // I can only return a state but update it after an AJAX request
    return {}
}
```

What's the best practice to do it.

Comment: When you say you `can't update state async` will you please explain what you mean and show us the code you've tried?

Comment: React intentionally deprecates `.componentWillReceiveProps()` to prevent misuse cases, and I suspect yours is one of those. You might want to describe your original intention, what are you trying to do here? Give us some context.

Comment: If your logic doesn't depends on `nextProps`, then you should use `componentDidUpdate()`. Even if it depends on `nextProps`, use `this.props` in that lifecycle instead is fine.

Comment: here's an update, some help pls

Comment: If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching AJAX call) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead.(https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops [for more info])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle for making api calls. Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` to make api call and once you get the api response do `this.setState`.  Also as pointed in another answer, you cannot use `this` in static method.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.myData !== prevProps.myData) {
      this.callMyApi();
    }
}

callMyApi() {
  fetch("/api")
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ ... });
    })
}
```

If you are writing new component, you can also consider to write a Functional component and use `useState` and `useEffect` to trigger api call when a propis updated.

**Like this:**

```js
...
  const {page} = this.props;
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/myfavApi`)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(images => {
        setImages(images.concat(images));
      });
  }, [page]); // provide page(prop) as dependency. 
  ...
```

Comment: It works, thank you. I'll try about Functional component if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The best place for do asynchronous calls is `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {}`. `getDerivedStateFromProps` is static method so it hasn’t access to component instance (hasn’t access to `this`)